# Erasing my Flash on STM32L1

Tags: c, embedded, flash-memory

I'm facing a problem with my erasing function.
I try to erase 15 sectors of my Flash in order to put a new binary file.
I don't understand why but my function freeze and i cannot erase all memory i need.

Here is my code if you want to give a try

```
/*
 * bootloader.c
 *
 *  Created on: 9 juin 2015
 *      Author: tgloaguen
 */
#include "usart.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_flash.h"
#define WRITE_START_ADDR 0x08000000
#define WRITE_END_ADDR 0x0800FFFF
#define FLASH_PAGE_SIZE    ((uint16_t)0x100) //If a page is 256 bits
#define MY_BL_FUNCTIONS __attribute__((section(".bootsection")))

void BootLoader(void) MY_BL_FUNCTIONS;
FLASH_Status Flash_Write ( uint32_t StartAddress, uint8_t *p, uint32_t Size ) MY_BL_FUNCTIONS;
uint8_t Flash_Erase() MY_BL_FUNCTIONS;
void Receive_Data(char * buffer,int size)MY_BL_FUNCTIONS;
void Receive_Size(char * buffer, int *sizeData)MY_BL_FUNCTIONS;

void BootLoader(void) {

    //clear all ITs
    USART_ITConfig( USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, DISABLE );
    //SendString("HELLO",USART2);
    uint8_t status,i;
    char buffer[33];
    //en dur
    uint16_t *adr = WRITE_START_ADDR;
    uint16_t sizeBin = 51400,k = 0,k_hexa = 0x20;
    SendString("BOOTLOADER",USART2);


    Flash_Erase();
    SendString("ERASEOK",USART2);
    //if sizeBin ok
}
```

and the erase function

```
uint8_t Flash_Erase() {

    uint32_t EraseCounter = 0x00, Address = 0x00;//Erase count, write address
    uint32_t NbrOfPage = 0x00;//Recording to erase the pages
    volatile FLASH_Status FLASHStatus = FLASH_COMPLETE;/*FLASH complete erasure marks*/
      /*Unlock FLASH*/

    FLASH_Unlock();
      /*Calculate the number of FLASH pages need to erase */
    NbrOfPage = (WRITE_END_ADDR - WRITE_START_ADDR) / FLASH_PAGE_SIZE;
      /* Remove all hang flags */
    FLASH_ClearFlag ( FLASH_FLAG_EOP     |
                            FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR  |
                            FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR  |
                            FLASH_FLAG_SIZERR  |
                            FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR );
      /* Erase the FLASH page*/
    for(EraseCounter = 0; (EraseCounter <NbrOfPage) && (FLASHStatus == FLASH_COMPLETE); EraseCounter++)
      {
        SendString("ok |",USART2);
        FLASHStatus = FLASH_ErasePage(WRITE_START_ADDR + (FLASH_PAGE_SIZE * EraseCounter));

      }
      FLASH_Lock ( );

    return (uint8_t)FLASHStatus;
}
```

Comment: Is your bootloader relocable? Are you running in RAM or is your bootloader on a flash page that is not cancelled by Flash_Erase func?

Comment: my bootloader is a the end of the FLASH, it is normally not erased by the function

Comment: If the Flash_Erase() function is executing from flash then I wouldn't expect it to work.  Imagine that while it's in the process of writing the flash erase commands it is also reading instructions from flash.  The instruction reads will interfere with the erase command sequence.  I believe you need to copy Flash_Erase() to RAM and execute it from there.  (The same goes for Flash_Program().)

Comment: @kkrambo Is usual in cortex M cores (or MCU without MMU) to erase/program program-flash excuting from flash. You have to take care/avoid to erase the sector/page that where the code is executing.

Comment: I just read ybout the STM32F4xx, so not sure if that applies to the 'L1xx, too (but most likely): While programming, accesses to the Flash stall. This might be a problem for interrupts. It would be helpful, if you add explicitly _what_ is going wrong. Did you read the "flash programming manual" for your device? If that runs under debugger control, there might be additional quirks (not sure about STM, but I had other MCUs exhibiting such problems).

Comment: Are you aware you are erasing the reset vectors and therefore make entry into the bootloader impossible? Not to talk about the interrupt verctors which instantly follow (Interrupts should be disabled anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are tring to erase the whole flash, but you are executing your bootloader from flash from final sectors.

As reported by th REF man

> During a write/erase operation to the NVM (except Half Page programming or Double-word
>   erase/write), any attempt to read the same bank of NVM stalls the bus.

Then you have to preserve the space of bootloader changing `WRITE_END_ADDR` define according to your memory map.

**Example:** if your bootloader is 4K long and belongs to the last sector `(0x0801 F000 - 0x0801 FFFF)` then `WRITE_END_ADDR` must be `0x0801 EFFF`.

**EDIT**
As @Olaf wrote take care about your ISP (Initial Stack Pointer) and IPC (Initial Program Counter) that belong to first 8 bytes in your flash at address 0.

Comment: He still would erase the reset vector, which is in the first sector.

Comment: @Olaf The problem is that the bootloader belongs at the end of flash, something that I totally disagree. Anyway is not a problem to cancel and re-flash the ISP and IPC, but is very risky. About vector table, lot of embedded tiny rtos (FreeRTOS, MQX...) remap the vector table to RAM at startup.I hope bootloader has vector table in its sector. Finally, OP can do what is trying to do, but the first time somethig go wrong (eg. power off during ISP and IPC re-write) the application is compromized.

Comment: In fact, what i'm trying to do here , is to write my own bootloader, I have to erase enought sectors to flash my new program from the USART . THe problem is i can only flash the first sector and it freeze, maybe my bootloader is at a wrong location and i attempt to read / write at the same time ... I checked my  linker script but i'm not sure how to place my bootloader where i want ....

Comment: my question is : where do i have to flash my new code ? do i have to let sector 0 because of the vector table ? and how do i put my bootloader at the end of the FLASH

Comment: It depends on many things. First of all: are you sure that your bootloader belongs to the last sector? If Yes, where its vector table belongs? Is the vector table RAM remapped at start of bootloader? If our bootloader maps the vector table from address 0 you cannot erase it and use uart via interrupt, for example. Anyway, my suggestion is to put the bootloader into the first sectors. This grants that IPC ans ISP are preserved on corruption.

Comment: FreeRTOS does definitvely _not_ remap the vector table - at least for ARM Cortex-M, it does not (I would know). For normal operation, at least the reset vecots are required to reside in Flash. It is also good practice: what happens if flashing fails (power break, unexpected reset/hard-falut/ etc.). That becomes even more critical, as he depends on an external system to get the data to flash properly.